# Does space itself fall into a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, event-horizon

Long time ago I heard someone say that it is space itself that falls into a black hole. Yesterday I saw a little animation that suggested the same (although I´m not sure, because the person who put the animation in the answer didn´t reply to my question). So I asked myself the question again. If that´s the case then this would also be true for the Earth. I´ve always learned that space is stationary around a massive object, and that the curvature of space-time causes objects to move to the mass. And not the picture that an object falls to a big piece of mass, because it´s riding along with the falling space. This suggests a completely different picture how gravity works. What´s playing here?

Comment: Space is stationary? You mean a nail that you nail into space won't move under the influence of gravity? Yeah, that would be kind of cool. :-)

Comment: If space is stationary, then how would you explain the recent LIGO results regarding gravity waves?

Comment: @count_to_10: Isn't that obvious? They didn't nail it... :-)

Comment: Of course space is not stationary, that why it can be deformed in all kinds of ways, dependent on time, like a gravity wave, but around the Earth spacetime is curved, and I always thougt that because of this curvature objects are falling to Earth, not because space itself is taking objects with is while falling to the Earth. How can space fall. It would be nice though to take a piece of space and nail it to...? :-)

Comment: Space isn't any-_thing_. If it was _a thing_, you could put a nail trough it, which would make for some really interesting inventions.

Comment: @CuriousOne But I was sure that that was how they held the set for "Interstellar" together for the filming!

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance: Don't get me started about all the bits they wasted on those CGI effects...

Comment: If we discover that spacetime is discrete, as in LQG, and CuriousOne discovers some tiny, tiny little nails that will fit between the cracks, you might have a point (sorry). https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_quantum_gravity

Comment: Space is a thing just like electrons or lions are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sound as though you may have heard of [Gullstrand Painlevé co-ordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gullstrand%E2%80%93Painlev%C3%A9_coordinates), which are a particular system of co-ordinates for labelling spacetime defined by the [Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) around a nonspinning, noncharged black hole.

The analogy is often made of a "spacetime river" with this depiction; if you stand still with respect to the co-ordinates you are in fact accelerating towards the hole, rather like being stationary in a strong rip or stream in the sea, watching the land go by as you are borne along by the current. To some degree the analogy is a pretty one as it evokes a fairly accurate feel for the motion of someone in freefall as seen by an observer at infinity or hovering just above the event horizon.

But it is important *always* to bear in mind that co-ordinates are simply the *labels* we give to the underlying spacetime manifold. So the physical reality is, rather obviously, exactly the same whether parameterized by GP co-ordinates or by Schwarzschild's originals. Spacetime is no more "flowing" in GP co-ordinates than it is for any other. And it's very hard to see a flowing analogy with other co-ordinates for the same, physical metric.

So in these lay pictures, you need to look at the underlying mathematics / physics and decide for yourself whether a particular analogy is helpful for your way of thinking. Flowing rivers do help many people to picture the situation, but always be clear that what you imagine is only an analogy and therefore cannot be relied upon to make all physical predictions.

By the way, these co-ordinates are almost certainly what Brian Cox has in mind when he describes passing through the event horizon by analogy with a [river current](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOqR1Csv7yg).

Comment: Kip S. Thorne used the same analogy in a talk of his that I attended. I have to say that it helps me to visualize certain scenarios, even though I am fully aware that _all_ coordinate systems are merely a figment of human imagination. Now let me get my hammer and some nails...

Comment: Hit it! And hit it again! :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne If space isn´t a thing (like the sauce between meatballs), then what ís it?:-)

Comment: @descheleschilder: Are you the kind of person who can take "We don't know." for a valid answer?

Comment: @CuriousOne I don´t know!:-)

Comment: @descheleschilder: You never know until you try.

Comment: @CuriousOne I´ll take thet in consideration!

Comment: @descheleschilder: Taking the plunge is fun.

Comment: @CuriousOne Okay! I´ll do it. Diving has always beem my speciality. And now we automatically move to chat!

Comment: @descheleschilder: That's just one of the options. :-)